# Can we access memory through a struct page structure

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Can we access memory through a struct page structure?

Note: The page belongs to high memory and has not been mapped to kernel logical address space.

Comment: plz elaborate what do you mean to access memory through struct page?

Comment: I mean when the virtual field of the struct page structure is NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes we can access the page belonging to highmem through struct page's virtual field. But in your case you can't access as you mentioned that highmem page is not mapped into kernel virtual memory.

To access it you need to create mapping either permanent or temporary mappping. 
To create permanent mapping map page through kmap.

```
 void *kmap(struct page *page)
```

This function works on either high or low memory. If the page structure belongs to a page in low memory, the page’s virtual address is simply returned. If the page resides in high memory, a permanent mapping is created and the address is returned.The function may sleep, so kmap() works only in process context. Because the number of permanent mappings are limited (if not, we would not be in this mess and could just permanently map all memory), high memory should be unmapped when no longer needed.This is done via the following function, which unmaps the given page:

```
void kunmap(struct page *page)
```

The temporary mapping can be created via:

```
void *kmap_atomic(struct page *page, enum km_type type)
```

This is an atomic function so you can't sleep and can be called in interrupt context. It is called temporary because next call to kmap_atomic will overwrite the previous mapping.

Answer (score 0):

in case there is no value for virtual field then you can not access that specific physical frame. the simple reason is struct page denotes the mappings between physical and virtual addresses so a system with large memory can not map all memory in kernel space. so high memory is mapped dynamically. but to access that memory it should be mapped i.e. void *virtual should not be NULL.